# How to get data from servlet in javaFX HttpRequest?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, javafx, client-server

I'm trying to create a client-server connection using **Servlets** for the server side, and in the client side I make requests with the help of `public class javafx.io.http.HttpRequest` in javaFX project. 
My problem is that I don't know how to properly get info from the javaFx `httpRequests` in the servlet and return response from the servlet in a way that the I will be able to read the response in the client side. 
Any ideas or examples for commands I should use in order to succeed in creating a good connection, sending objects in the request and getting objects back from the servlet??

Thanks.

Comment: What info are you talking about? Passing information to a servlet is usually done using GET parameters or POSTing data to it. I'm sure there are lots of tutorials out there...

Comment: if I get your question, you are asking how to send request to servlet and get back the response . is it what you are askin ?

Comment: by info I mean for example attributes or JSON objects.
And yes I'm asking how can get the response back with this kind of HTTP request .

Answer (score 0):

[`javafx.io.http.HttpRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.io.http/javafx.io.http.HttpRequest.html) is a JavaFX 1.3 API.  JavaFX 1.3 is [totally obsolete, unsupported and unmaintained](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#9) by Oracle or anybody else.  Use of it is not recommended.  Even the link to the End of Life announcement is obsolete and no longer works ;-)

Instead use [JavaFX APIs for Java 8 or 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html#JavaFX), some [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) for that is provided by Oracle.

JavaFX 9 APIs do not provide a specific HttpRequest API.  There are however ways to make Http requests already in Java, (for instance the [URL connection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection--)).  There are also many third party libraries which could be used, for example [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or the [Java 9 Http Client incubator project](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/03/14/getting-started-with-java9-httpclient.html).  There are tutorials on the web which teach how to use these things.

Another alternative is that you could use a framework such as [RestEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org) which provides for rest based calls from client apps to server apps (this is probably the approach I would recommend).  Detailing how this would work with a sample is outside the scope of a StackOverflow answer, but just read the [RestEasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) and it explain how to do this.